# Automating Watin with IE10 and TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, watin

I've upgraded internet explorer to version 10 on one of the team city build agents. After the upgrade, our Watin acceptance tests will not run. I get exceptions like:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException : This function is not supported on this system. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070078)

The Team City build agent is running as local system account with access to desktop and needles to say, our tests used to work on older versions of IE. Things I've tried: changed the service log on to localadmin, disabling uac; still get the same errors. If I remote onto the build agent and fire up powershell as administrator I can run the tests successfully. If I fire up powershell without elevating to admin, I am not able to run the tests. The server is Server 2008 R2 SP1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet Explorer 10 does not appear on the list of supported browsers, so it may not be possible to get it to work with IE10.

From [the WatiN home page]

> Works with Internet Explorer 6, 7, 8, 9 and FireFox 2 and 3

Link Removed - Domain hijacked by Spammers 
See https://web.archive.org/web/20161230004014/http://watin.org/ for old versions of the site)

Comment: Seen it, I am porting to Selenium as we speak, sad to say, but Watin seems dead..

Comment: Just to add to this, WatiN doesn't work with IE10 or 11 primarily due to the way it tries to inject javascript into a page. IE10 replaced the method for doing this with another one and WatiN has not been updated to use the new method.

Answer (score 0):

Also from the Watin website: Latest release is WatiN 2.1 (released on 12 April 2011).
Time to port to Selenium alright.